# multiple embed tags for sound files

Tags: javascript

This javascript + html tag work if only one sound file is on the page.  It fails for multiple tags:

```
<script language='JavaScript'>
function play(url,n){

stopAllMusic (n);
var sound = 'sound' +n;

var soundElement = document.createElement('embed');
soundElement.src = url;
soundElement.autostart = 'true';
soundElement.hidden = 'true';

// Select the sound container (the <span> tag)
var soundContainer = document.getElementById(sound);

soundContainer.appendChild(soundElement);
}

function stopAllMusic (n){
var sound = 'sound' +n;
document.getElementById(sound).innerHTML = '';
}
```

Relevant html parts:
first one:-

```
<img src='img/play.gif' onclick="play('media/a1.mp3', 1);" >
<span id = sound1><embed src='media/a1.mp3' style='display:none' loop='false' autostart='false' hidden='false'/></span>
```

second:

```
<img src='img/play.gif' onclick="play('media/a2.mp3', 2);" >
<span id = sound2><embed src='media/a2.mp3' style='display:none' loop='false' autostart='false' hidden='false'/></span>
```

There are many sound files on the same page.  I wonder if one cannot have several src files on the same page, or perhaps something is wrong with the code?  Thanks a lot

I am using both IE + FF.

Comment: What browser are you using?

Comment: @Jess Could you add a fiddle?

Comment: @Manu  I am using IE + FF

Comment: @Ash  sorry a newbie here on Stack Overflow - not sure yet how to use comments so I edited the post and added the comment at the bottom Thanks

Comment: I suggest to use the audio tag in HTML5, http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_audio.asp

Comment: @ SalDev HTML5 doesn't work with IE8 but link is very useful. Thanks.  It would be very convenient to get the script posted above to work.  What happens when play buton is clicked is that it keeps trying to load and then it hangs.  I wonder if multiple audios on the same page is confusing the script?